# S3 Bucket is outputting strange blank links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my view I generate resigned URL's which allow users to access a document from the S3m, however when I attempt to click through the link, I'm brought to a blank page, which the URL far longer than I'm expecting, and I can't see the cause of this in my code. Attached is what I believe is the relevant code.

The outputted URL

```
https://textract-console-eu-central-1-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxa-02037xxxx50.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/archive/31.08.2021/dummy.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA5G3B5AMUYTIRW7PU%2F20210906%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210906T180658Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=315f30af7434aff065ebec60f13f0ab34d872c84df132dd3e37c5e764bd7cfe7
```

My ActiveRecordSerializer.rb

```
  module Panel
  module InternalApi
    class OcrDocumentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :case_file_slug, :status, :data, :log, :object_key, :download_link, :verifiable, :type

      has_many :users, key: :verifiers, serializer: VerifiersSerializer

      def attachment_name
        binding.pry
        object.attachment&.file_file_name
      end

      def attachment_id
        object.attachment&.id
        binding.pry
      end

      def data
        object.data.to_h.reject { |_, v| v.blank? }
      end

      def case_file_slug
        object.case_file&.slug
      end

      def download_link
        return if object.object_key.blank?
        object.document.expiring_url
      end

      def verifiable
        object.users.pluck(:id).exclude?(current_user.id) && object.status == 'need_verification'
      end

      def current_user
        scope
      end
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:: Here is the response request when I click into the link.

```
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type
Date: Mon, 06 Sep 2021 18:07:04 GMT
ETag: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Sep 2021 07:00:29 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-expiration: expiry-date="Thu, 09 Sep 2021 00:00:00 GMT", rule-id="ZDUyZmY1MTYtZTE2OS00MzQzLThjMWMtZWE0NTQ3ZTZkNjA3"
x-amz-id-2: zd1UsxwD8du4Ucotsp77lBHUWSAlu+VcAo0QcgHGt1+ZSF/2ieXMnHJtprXzmcyE9aebsB9MWIM=
x-amz-meta-new_key: ok
x-amz-request-id: N3CN33YZFVV4W1YY
```

Comment: In what way is that url longer than expected? What is on the blank page actually, any errors, does a download start, …?

Comment: @luk2302 Perhaps I'm wrong RE the length. The blank page has no errors, on inspect its just empty HTML, no download is started either. I should see the line of text which is on the document.

Comment: And you are sure you are not maybe just looking at an empty pdf file? Can you post one full presigned url auch that we can maybe check for errors ourselves?

Comment: @luk2302, url 'auch'? I've attached the Response Headers I receive upon clicking said link, I'm not sure if that helps. And I've double checked the file contents, it contains a line of text which isn't displayed when clicking through the link.

Comment: that was supposed to be a “such” - are you sure there is a non-zero-length file at that location in the bucket?

Comment: @luk2302 100%, here is a fresh presigned URL https://textract-console-eu-central-1-3469d743-0840-45e0-95fa-020378550.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/archive/31.08.2021/dummy.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA5G3B5AMUYTIRW7PU%2F20210906%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210906T185824Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a17b0e5e721f9cc4a86563e4b22901c000b503c4c9a08b566055cf9459f8ab02

Comment: I would say that is an empty file. Or *maybe* related to s3 object-lambda which I have no experience with...